# Using Gravity Forms gform_field_validation for Full Name to check for first and last name

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, forms, gravityforms

I want to use the [gform_field_validation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/) function from Gravity Forms to validate a Full Name field only if there's a space between the two names, validating that someone didn't just put in one name, and put it a first and last name.

I believe I've found the correct Regex to do it /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
. Just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Check the *6. Phone field validation* section with phone number validation, it shows how to use a regex. BTW, it should be `^\S+\s+\S+$`, shouldn't it? Two words with one or more whitespace in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', 'validate_fullname', 10, 4 );
function validate_fullname( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $pattern = "/^\w+\s\w+$/";
    if ( ! preg_match( $pattern, $value ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'Please enter a valid full name';
    } else {
        $result['is_valid'] = true;
        $result['message']  = '';
    }
 
    return $result;
}
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of string
- `\w+` - 1+ word characters
- `\s` - a single space
- `\w+` - 1+ word characters
- `$` - anchor at end of string

You might want a more forgiving regex allowing with multiple words:

```
    $pattern = "/^\w+(\s\w+)+$/";
```

Explanation:

- `(\s\w+)+` - one or more sequences of space followed by word chars